# Very large array Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a very large array (for example 30,000 items). i get it as a stream using grpc-web.

i get the data from the grpc.client() and push it into an array and then display the array using `*ngFor`, but it is kinda slow and laggy. is there any other way i can display the data ? i thought about using Observable array then using the `async` pipe but i can't quite understand how to do it and wheter it will help.

here is the code :

```
book.component.ts

queryBooks() {
const client = grpc.client(BookService.QueryBooks, {
  host: host,
});
client.onHeaders((headers: grpc.Metadata) => {
  // console.log("queryBooks.onHeaders", headers);
});
client.onMessage((message: Book) => {
 this.books.push(message.toObject())
});
client.onEnd((code: grpc.Code, msg: string, trailers: grpc.Metadata) => {
  trailers :', trailers);
});
client.start();
client.send(queryBooksRequest);
```

}

i'm not sure that an observable will solve the problem, but it is very laggy.

Comment: Do you really need all the 30k rows at once? Can you not do some sort of pagination and only fetch `n` items at a time?

Comment: i can add pagination, but i need to get all 30k items from the server at once, is there a way to add/remove items based on scroll ? @bugs

Comment: You are probably looking for virtual scrolling https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling

Comment: You can also use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` with `ChangeDetectorRef.detectchanges()`

Comment: this is exactly what i need! do i have to use angular material to use it ? or is there any other library ? @Ploppy

Comment: @KLTR This is in the Material CDK, you don't need Material itself to use it.

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi Even using OnPush and trackBy, 30k rows will be a horror of you render them all.

Comment: Manipulating thousands of elements in DOM would definitely slow down the rendering, let be via jQuery or Angular (though there are optimization done in this area). I believe you need to revisit the strategy of what amout of data you want to render.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ploppy suggested you could use the data table from angular material cdk.

This will limit the amount of elements that are currently in the dom, and significantly speed up the render.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose to use pagination, if it's not possible on the server-side, you can implement it on client-side. For 30 000 items problems even not in angular, there will generate too many html elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PrimeNG for use its components, there is one that solves your problem, doing scrolling for only load data that showed.

For table: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/scroll

'Simple' data: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/virtualscroller

For use PrimeNG: https://alligator.io/angular/primeng/